# An issue with AVSpeechSynthesizer, Any workarounds?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer to play text. I have an array of utterances to play.

```
    NSMutableArray *utterances = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *text in textArray) {
        AVSpeechUtterance *welcome = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:text];
        welcome.rate = 0.25;
        welcome.voice = voice;
        welcome.pitchMultiplier = 1.2;
        welcome.postUtteranceDelay = 0.25;
        [utterances addObject:welcome];
    }
    lastUtterance = [utterances lastObject];
    for (AVSpeechUtterance *utterance in utterances) {
        [speech speakUtterance:utterance];
    }
```

I have a cancel button to stop speaking. When I click the cancel button when the first utterance is spoken, the speech stops and it clears all the utterances in the queue. If I press the cancel button after the first utterance is spoken (i.e. second utterance), then stopping the speech does not flush the utterances queue. The code that I am using for this is:

```
  [speech stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
```

Can someone confirm if this is a bug in the API or am I using the API incorrectly? If it is a bug, is there any workaround to resolve this issue?

Comment: People have already filed bug reports about this. Consider filing a duplicate so it gets fixed faster! http://openradar.appspot.com/search?query=AVSpeechSynthesizer+

Comment: I assume the stopping will not work ONLY if you try to stop the utterance when the synthesizer is in between the point of having finished reading the first utterance and starting to read the second one. If so, refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39422205/3930247

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quite likely to be a bug, in that the delegate method *synthesizer didCancelSpeechUtterance* isn't called after the first utterance;

A workaround would be to chain the utterances rather than have them in an array and queue them up at once.

Use the delegate method *synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance* to increment an array pointer and speak the the next text from that array. Then when trying to stop the speech, set a BOOL that is checked in this delegate method before attempting to speak the next text.

For example:

1) implement the protocol in the view controller that is doing the speech synthesis

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import AVFoundation;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate>

@end
```

2) instantiate the AVSpeechSynthesizer and set its delegate to self

```
speechSynthesizer   = [AVSpeechSynthesizer new];
speechSynthesizer.delegate = self;
```

3) use an utterance counter, set to zero at start of speaking

4) use an array of texts to speak

```
textArray           = @[@"Mary had a little lamb, its fleece",
                        @"was white as snow",
                        @"and everywhere that Mary went",
                        @"that sheep was sure to go"];
```

5) add delegate method didFinishSpeechUtterance to speak the next utterance from the array 
of texts and increment the utterance counter

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{
    if(utteranceCounter < utterances.count){
        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = utterances[utteranceCounter];
        [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
        utteranceCounter++;
    }
}
```

5) to stop speaking, set the utterance counter to the count of the texts array and attempt to get the synthesizer to stop

```
utteranceCounter = utterances.count;

BOOL speechStopped =  [speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
if(!speechStopped){
    [speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryWord];
}
```

6) when speaking again, reset the utterance counter to zero

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was an issue with didFinishSpeechUtterance. Even that was not getting called, after the first utterance! But will double check.

Comment: didCancelSpeechUtterance does not work with the same AVSpeechSynthesizer object even though the utterances are chained. So I created a speakInternal method as answered below.

Answer (score 24):

I found a workaround :

```
- (void)stopSpeech
{
    if([_speechSynthesizer isSpeaking]) {
        [_speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@""];
        [_speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
        [_speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];    
    }
}
```

Call `stopSpeakingAtBoundary:`, enqueue an empty utterance and call `stopSpeakingAtBoundary:` again to stop and clean the queue.

Comment: This is really the best answer to the question.

Comment: I've still seen some issues using this method, nothing I can reproduce but with a large userbase on our app the bug still can occur on a very few users. Having your own queue like the accepted answer combined with this one is now my best approach for the next version.

Answer (score 6):

All answers here failed, and what I came up with is stopping the synthesizer and then re-instantiate it:

```
- (void)stopSpeech
{
    if([_speechSynthesizer isSpeaking]) {
        [_speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
        _speechSynthesizer = [AVSpeechSynthesizer new];
        _speechSynthesizer.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This solution is definitely working for me !!

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to what SPA mentioned. Speaking one item at a time from a loop.
Here is the idea..

```
NSMutableArray *arr; //array of NSStrings, declared as property
AVSpeechUtterance *currentUtterence;  //declared as property
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer; //property

- (void) viewDidLoad:(BOOL)anim
{
    [super viewDidLoad:anim];
    synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];

    //EDIT -- Added the line below
    synthesizer.delegate = self;

    arr = [self populateArrayWithString]; //generates strings to speak
}

//assuming one thread will call this
- (void) speakNext
{
   if (arr.count > 0)
   {
        NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
        [arr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        currentUtterence = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:str];

        //EDIT -- Commentted out the line below
        //currentUtterence.delegate = self;
        [synthesizer speakUtterance:utteranc];
    }
}

- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)avsSynthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance
{
    if ([synthesizer isEqual:avsSynthesizer] && [utterance isEqual:currentUtterence])
        [self speakNext];
}

- (IBOutlet) userTappedCancelledButton:(id)sender
{
    //EDIT <- replaced the object the method gets called on.
    [synthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
    [arr removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: AVSpeechUtterance does not have any delegate: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechUtterance_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Modified the code to reflect the API. I did something similar and it did not work. Because the delegate functions did not get triggered appropriately.

Comment: I've edited the code to fix the issue you reported. It was my mistake since I was typing it from my memory.

Answer (score 1):

didCancelSpeechUtterance does not work with the same AVSpeechSynthesizer object even though the utterances are chained in the didFinishSpeechUtterance method.

```
-(void)speakInternal
{
    speech = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    speech.delegate = self;
    [speech speakUtterance:[utterances objectAtIndex:position++]];
}
```

In speakInternal, I am creating AVSpeechSynthesizer object multiple times to ensure that didCancelSpeechUtterance works. Kind of a workaround.

Comment: On 7.1 I'm still seeing this issue. Getting a fresh Synthesizer is still the only way to make the "queue" behave. http://timbroder.com/2014/03/avspeechsynthesizers-queue-doesnt-work.html

Comment: I do this too. But I think that it doesn't work well for the battery.