# AVSpeechSynthesizer postUtteranceDelay timing problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avspeechsynthesizer

The code below takes a list of directions and reads them out using AVSpeechSynthesizer. Once complete, the user will be able to select a variable amount of time and the app will read out the instructions to fit the time span.

The problem is that when I press the play button, the delay between directions is significantly longer than it should be. Instead of the two minutes I've hardcoded it with, it takes over three. I've logged the value of all my postUtteranceDelays and they add up properly. It's also not due to processing time because when set postUtteranceDelay to 0 there is no pause between directions. I'm not sure what is going on.

```
- (IBAction)play:(UIButton *)sender {
[sender setTitle:@"Showering" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
Shower *shower = [[SpecificShower alloc] init];

NSUInteger totalRatio = [shower calculateTotalRatio:shower];
NSNumber *offset = @18.0; // estimated time to speak instructions combined
NSNumber *seconds = @120.0; // hard coded but just for testing
int totalSeconds = seconds.intValue - offset.intValue;

self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary* direction in shower.directions) {

    AVSpeechUtterance *aDirection = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:direction[@"text"]];
    NSNumber *directionLength = direction[@"length"];
    aDirection.rate = .3;
    aDirection.preUtteranceDelay = 0;
    // totalRatio is calculated by adding all the lengths together 
    // then the individual direction length is divided by totalRatio
    // and that fraction is multiplied by total number of seconds
    // to come up with the postUtteranceDelay for each direction
    aDirection.postUtteranceDelay = totalSeconds * [directionLength floatValue]/totalRatio;
    NSLog(@"%f", aDirection.postUtteranceDelay);
    [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:aDirection];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not alone. This seems to be a bug as noted with a workaround over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22229111/606711).
There are also radars filed [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/16205032) and [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/15546872).

Let's hope this gets fixed soon.

Comment: I found a similar issue, when I set postUtteranceDelay = 0.3, sometimes didStartSpeechUtterance will not be fired any more, and if I set postUtteranceDelay = 0, everything is fine. This only happen on iOS8

Comment: The OP is asking about the delay issue, not the stopping utterance issue.