# AVAudioSession never stopped

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avaudiosession

I'm trying to set my `AVAudioSession` to inactive to get back to normal state.

My utterance function:

```
class SSpeech : NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

    var group = DispatchGroup();
    var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "co.xxxx.speech", attributes: [])

    class var sharedInstance: SSpeech {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: SSpeech?
        }
        if !(Static.instance != nil) {
            Static.instance = SSpeech()
        }
       return Static.instance!
    }

   required override init() {
       super.init();
       self.speechsynt.delegate = self;
   }

   deinit {
      print("deinit SSpeech")
   }

   let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();
   var speechsynt: AVSpeechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
   var queueTalks = SQueue<String>();

   func pause() {
        speechsynt.pauseSpeaking(at: .word)
   }

   func talk(_ sentence: String, languageCode code:String = SUtils.selectedLanguage.code, withEndPausing: Bool = false) {
       if SUser.sharedInstance.currentUser.value!.speechOn != 1 {
           return
        }

        queue.async{            
            self.queueTalks.enQueue(sentence)
            do {
                let category = AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback;
                var categoryOptions = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers
                if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                    categoryOptions.formUnion(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers)
                 }
                try self.audioSession.setCategory(category, with: categoryOptions)
                try self.audioSession.setActive(true);
            } catch _ {
                return;
            }

            self.utteranceTalk(sentence, initSentence: false, speechsynt: self.speechsynt, languageCode:code, withEndPausing: withEndPausing)

            do {
                try self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
            } catch _ {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    func utteranceTalk(_ sentence: String, initSentence: Bool, speechsynt: AVSpeechSynthesizer, languageCode:String = "en-US", withEndPausing: Bool = false){
        if SUser.sharedInstance.currentUser.value!.speechOn != 1 {
            return
        }

        let nextSpeech:AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: sentence)
        nextSpeech.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: languageCode)
        if !initSentence {
            nextSpeech.rate = 0.4;
        }

        if(withEndPausing){
            nextSpeech.postUtteranceDelay = 0.2;
        }
        speechsynt.speak(nextSpeech)
    }


    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance:AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("Speaker has finished to talk")

        queue.async {
               do {
                   try self.audioSession.setActive(false, with: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
               }
               catch {}
           }
       }
    }
}
```

My method is correctly called, but my `audioSession` still active when the `utterance` is finished. i've tried lot of thing but nothing work :(.

Comment: maybe have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893007/how-to-consistently-stop-avaudiosession-after-avspeechutterance?rq=1)

Comment: @GCBenson Thank's for the link, but can't solve it with it :(

Comment: @Makaille How did you check that `audioSession` is still active?

Comment: @arunjos007 i'm not sure to understand what you mean. You want to know how i know my audio session still active ?

Comment: @Makaille Yes that's it

Comment: @arunjos007 just a supposition cause like i said, the music still in background with a bad quality and a low volume et never back to old state

Comment: @Makaille, have you checked my suggestion?

Comment: @NeverHopeless Yes but didn't try for the moment (i'm on holiday). Don't worry i'll ask you :)

Comment: @Makaille did you fixed this? Have the same problem. Connected to Bluetooth in Car with Hands free protocol and after speech it dont hang up and the music is interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an AvAudioPlayer. They have very easy start and stop commands.

first declare the audio player as a variable

```
var SoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!
```

then select the file you need

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Untitled2.wav", ofType:nil)!
                    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                        SoundEffect = sound
                        sound.numberOfLoops = -1
                        sound.play()
```

and to stop the audio player

```
if SoundEffect != nil {
            SoundEffect.stop()
            SoundEffect = nil
        }
```

Comment: Thank's for you answer but i'm not using a player and any wav or other sound file. I create the sound by String that's why i'm using a speechSynthetizer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop or deactive `AudioSession`, your app gets it upon launching. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession):

> An audio session is the intermediary between your app and iOS used to configure your app’s audio behavior. Upon launch, your app **automatically gets** a singleton audio session.

So method `-setActive:` does not make your `AudioSession` "active", it just puts its category and mode configuration into action. For getting back to the "normal state", you could set [default settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW5) or just call `setActive(false, with:.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)`, that will be enough.

Comment: As you can see that's what i'm doing and i'm trying to found why the result excepted isn't present. I call `setActive(false, with:.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)` but it changes nothing

Comment: And I said you do it right:) What kind of result do you expect? Method `setActive(false)` should not change smth, it just says to system media demon, that your application does not need the previous audio settings. If you want to reset some settings you need deactivate audio session, change settings to default, activate it.

Comment: Currently, i'm listening music from spotify on my headphone (for example), my app will talk "You are running 10km...". So the sound of my music will be low, during the talk. When the speech is finished, the music from spotify doesn't go back to his previous volume.

Comment: Okey. For interrupting background sound followed by restoring, you need set proper category (in your case `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`) without any option (other audio interruption is by default), activate `AudioSession` and deactivate it, when you finish playing.

Comment: I am hooking in here, because I have a similar problem to that. Instantiating an AudioSession does indeed influence other portions of your app. Eg. AVPlayer will not start to play if an AudioSession was instantiated before ... I could not figure out to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

A part from [documentation of AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616627-setactive):

> **Discussion**
>
> If another active audio session has higher priority than yours (for
>   example, a phone call), and neither audio session allows mixing,
>   attempting to activate your audio session fails. **Deactivating your
>   session will fail if any associated audio objects (such as queues,
>   converters, players, or recorders) *are currently running.***

My guess is that the failure to deactivate the session is the running process(es) of your `queue` as I highlighted in the document quote.

Probably you should make the deactivation process *synchronous* instead of *asynchronous* OR *make sure that all the running actions under your `queue` has been processed*.

Give this a try:

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance:AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("Speaker has finished to talk")

        queue.sync { // <---- `async` changed to `sync`
               do {
                   try self.audioSession.setActive(false, with: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
               }
               catch {}
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, i'm back and this not working more in synchronous. I've done different test, the bad comportement appears when i'm connect to the audio with a bluethoot equipement.

Comment: ok for the time being and to test, can you add a delay of say 10-15 sec and then try to deactivate sound it may be fail due to some pending running operation in queue.