# Unable to set AudioSession inactive with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I am using an `AVPlayer` to playback audio in my iOS app (because the audio files I'm playing are not local), and when my track finishes, I want to hide the InfoCenter controls, but I get this error:

`AVAudioSession.mm:1079:-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.`

I am however pausing my `AVPlayer` before.

This is my code:

```swift
player.pause()
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nil
try? audioSession.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

Due to this error, the native controls remain visible, but don't work anymore.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373486/avaudiosession-never-stopped

Comment: Mh... that doesn't really help me. I'm not using a queue.. I only have a single `AVPlayer` that plays one track at a time...

Comment: I guess [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626384/9224215) will help you with this.

Comment: What if you stop instead of pause?

Comment: @matt AVPlayer do not have stop functionality like AVAudioPlayer have

Comment: @Abdorahman Yes, I see, you're right. There isn't some simple way to say "release the buffer".

Comment: @matt there is a way just like my answer below

Comment: @Abdorahman Yes, I think you've made that point already.

Comment: @enyo do my solution worked for you?

Comment: @Abdorahman I'll be able to confirm Monday! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to lose the lock screen controls is to make your audio session mixable (*without* deactivating your audio session):

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

Remove the `.mixWithOthers` when you want them back.

Another, perhaps more palatable way is to remove your `MPRemoteCommandCenter` targets once you pause playback. e.g. if you set it up like this

```
var playTarget: Any? = nil
var pauseTarget: Any? = nil

func addRemoteTargets() {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    playTarget = commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        print("play \(event)")
        return .success
    }

    pauseTarget = commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        print("pause \(event)")
        return .success
    }
}
```

Then remove the targets like so:

```
func removeRemoteTargets() {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(playTarget)
    playTarget = nil
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(pauseTarget)
    pauseTarget = nil
}
```

p.s. these are "seems to work!" answers. I don't know how you are supposed to determine when an `AVPlayer` has finished its audio I/O (apart from polling via `setActive:false` failing). My reasoning is that becoming the lock screen/"Now Playing App" has 3 pieces (this is sort of documented somewhere, [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/handling_external_player_events_notifications) is the closest thing I can find to that right now, although the most explicit documentation of how this works is in the system logs):

1. a non mixable audio session category
2. `MPRemoteCommandCenter` integration
3. current or "recently" finished audio IO

so if you can remove any one of these pieces, the lock screen controls should go away.

Comment: Removing the `togglePlayPauseCommand` target was the only thing that worked for me. All the other tips (setting the player to `nil`, etc...) didn't change anything to the error message I was getting.

Comment: Any commands you add you must also remove, I should make that explicit

Comment: Yes, that was clear to me. I have removed all the targets I was using and it worked. My comment was in reference to the other solutions, which did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

`AVPlayer` doesn't stop instantly, so you need to subscribe for its status change to catch when it got paused. Only then you can deactivate the `AVAudioSession` safely.

#### Swift 5 example

```
var timeControlObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
timeControlObservation = player.observe(\.timeControlStatus, changeHandler: { [weak player] (_, _) in
    guard let player = player else {
        return
    }
    if player.timeControlStatus != .playing {
        // Finish your work here
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        timeControlObservation = nil
    }
}
player.pause()
```

Answer (score 1):

You getting that error because you are deactivating the audio session before deallocating the player:
you can deallocate it with:

```
play.pause()
player = nil
```

but you should declare your player as optional first.
You question is related to:
[Impossible to stop AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993896/impossible-to-stop-avplayer)

Answer (score 0):

You've to remove

```
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nil
```

An only keep this

```
player.pause()
try? audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

Comment: This didn't work. Still got: `Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
player.pause()
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
player = nil
```